# using formula array and trend in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

I would like to do a linear regression between two excel vba arrays, then copy the predicted values into the spreadsheet.

So far, I have the two arrays and I'm trying to use the excel trend function, but the spreadsheet array is filled with one value multiple times.

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("M3").Resize(daycount, 1).FormulaArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(yvalues, xvalues)
```

My output is in column M:

```
-64.1022
-64.1022
-64.1022
-64.1022
-64.1022
```

when it should be different values.

Any idea what the problem is? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Guys, I think that the problem has to do with the fact that the arrays that I am using are stored in vba, not on the spreadsheet. The data is taken from the spreasheet, processed, and then used to construct a trend line, so the yvalues and xvalues that I am using do not appear on the spreadsheet. I hope this is clear. I have tried both your solutions and they do work when you use a range from a spreadsheet, but not when you input vba arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting values not formula; therefore use ".Value" instead of ".FormulaArray".

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("M3").Resize(daycount, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(yvalues, xvalues)
```

**EDIT:**

Beware of the arrays dimetion.
To be able to insert an array directly into a range, it is necesary to be in a (1 to n, 1 to 1) array dimention.
The *TREND* worksheetfunction accepts as arguments one dimentional array (1 to n) and also 2 dimentional array (1 to n, 1 to 1). Important is to note that the array delivered by the TREND function will have the same dimention as your ***yvalues*** and ***xvalues*** array.

So why this worked:

```
...=Array(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(yvalues, xvalues))
```

Because `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(yvalues, xvalues)` delivered a unidimentional array and then when passed this as argument to the Array(..) function, it turned into a two dimentional array.

Comment: I tried using `.Value` instead, but got the same result. Any other ideas? I've checked my arrays (yvalues and xvalues) and they appear to be correct.

Comment: @sar: Are your arrays arranged in vertical form? Your index for the arrays should be something like: yvalues (1 to daycount, 1 to 1) and not yvalues (1 to 1, 1 to daycount)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something wrong with the range that's receiving the value. Try to assign it to a range object and then apply the formula itself.

Are both Target / X / Y ranges with same size? Not sure if they'd work if not.

Just tried the code below and worked fine (i.e. target range got decimal values, as expected).

FYI, I set range A1:A5 as [1 2 3 4 5] and B1:B5 as [100 10 5 2 1].

```
Sub TestTrend()

    Dim oRange As Excel.Range
    Dim oRangeX As Excel.Range
    Dim oRangeY As Excel.Range

    Set oRange = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("C1:C5")
    Set oRangeX = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1:A5")
    Set oRangeY = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B1:B5")

    oRange.FormulaArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(oRangeX, oRangeY)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!!

The correct call is

```
    ...=Array(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(yvalues, xvalues))
```

then vba returns an array from the function, not just a single value.

Comment: I still believe the problem you get was because you were applying a value into a unique range (M3) and then resizing it. If you set the _Range("M3").Resize(daycount, 1)_ range into a specific range object and then assign the trend value (without array) it might work as well (as per my below example).